# Warning: Illegal string offset 'size'

Tags: php, wordpress, warning

помогите разобраться пожалуйста. На страницах почти везде данное сообщение:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'size' in
>   "/home/...lib/required/customization.php on line 924

вот часть кода строки, где возникает ошибка:

```
if(!$atts['size'])
    $atts['size'] = 'thumbnail';
```

Полностью Код:

```
// 5: Post Thumbnail Plugin *****/

function post_thumbnail_shortcode($atts, $content='') {
    if(!function_exists('post_thumbnail_shortcode'))
        return;

    if(!$atts['size'])
        $atts['size'] = 'thumbnail';

    return '<figure class="post_thumbnail th '.$atts['class'].'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(null, 'img_full').'</figure>';
}

function post_thumbnail($str){
    $args = wp_parse_args($str);
    echo post_thumbnail_shortcode($args);
}

add_shortcode('post_thumbnail', 'post_thumbnail_shortcode');
```

Comment: если можно, пожалуйста, желательно с примером кода, как и на что мне заменить или исправить. я плохо разбираюсь в этом.

Comment: А как сам shortcode вставлен?

Comment: Веселый код. Существование функции проверяют внутри самой функции

Comment: `var_dump($atts);` что показывает? Может плохо вызываете.

Answer (score 0):

1. Это происходит из-за того что `$atts` это строка а не массив.
2. Судя по коду `$atts['size']` у вас дальше нигде не используется. По идее он должен быть передан в функцию `get_the_post_thumbnail(null, $atts['size'])`
3. По хорошему вам нужно понять что приходит в функцию в этом случае и почему.

Предположу что такое приходит по причине того что вы создаете пустой шорткат.
Например: `[post_thumbnail]`

Функцию можно переписать вот так:

```
function post_thumbnail_shortcode($atts, $content = '') {

    $extra_class = '';
    $size = 'thumbnail';
    if (is_array($atts)) {
        if (isset($atts['size'])) {
            if ($current_size = trim($atts['size'])) {
                $size = $current_size;
            }
        }
        if (isset($atts['class']))) {
            if ($current_class = trim($atts['class'])) {
                $extra_class = $current_class;
            }
        }
    }

    return '<figure class="post_thumbnail th'.$extra_class.'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(null, $size).'</figure>';
}
```

Теперь шорткат без свойств получит поведение по умолчанию, но мы так же можем задать ему поведение  `[post_thumbnail size=img_full class=bordered]`

Вот [статья](https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:Shortcode_API) про то как работают шорт-коды